# Mongoose with Promise and callback

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

I am having issue to understand the difference between the following piece of code in connecting to MongoDB.

```
1: mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err) => {
if (err) {
    return err
}
console.log('connected to DB!');
})

2: mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
mongoose.connection
   .on('error', (error) => {
        console.warn(error)})
   .once('open', () => {
        console.log('connected to DB!')})

3: mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('connected to DB!'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

So from they way I understand is that `mongoose.connect` return a Promise and we have to handle promise with eihter `.then.catch` or `aync/await` but in here its used a callback function also.
Can someone explain this 3 methods to me?

Comment: In your three examples, the only difference is how errors are handled (`console.log` vs `console.warn` vs ignoring). In general, they do the same thing, not sure what exactly you want explained. Have a look at the usage in real-world code.

Comment: I was actually asking if it possible to always handle promise with callback functions? because I knew we handle it using .then and async/await

Comment: Still not clear to me. What you are passing to `then` and `catch` are callback functions. Is it that?

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 and 3 are doing the same thing: they handle the initial connection success/failure. As not everybody use promises, they offer a mean to handle it with a callback as well. In both case, the callback/promise will be called during at the first connection, later failure during execution will not. You should of course use only one feature at a time, either callback or promise.

Number 2 add an event listenner that will trigger its callback everytime an error occur with the connection, not just during the initial connection. It can be used in addition to number 1 and 3 to handle error during the lifetime of your program.

More info here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling

Comment: Thanks but from my knowledge, I handle promise with .then/.catch OR async/await. Never handled Promises with callbacks and I  get confuse

Comment: You're correct on the promise handling. You don't handle a Promise with a callback: mongoose call you're callback if provided, otherwise it return the Promise.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to study and have into consideration:

1. understanding Promises vs Callbacks; understading error handling
   (try...catch); understanding concepts handling (promises;
   async/await; callback)
2. what the code #1, #2 and #3 means and is doing

**On the concepts**

Some pretty good recent links:

- on [Promises vs Callback](https://itnext.io/javascript-promises-vs-rxjs-observables-de5309583ca2#:%7E:text=The%20main%20difference%20between%20callbacks,do%20when%20the%20asynchronous%20task) and [Using Promises and Chaining Concept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- on [try... catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)
- on [async/await](https://blog.pusher.com/promises-async-await/#:%7E:text=First%2C%20async%2Fawait%20makes%20the,and%20behave%20like%20synchronous%20code.&text=Just%20like%20Promises%20themselves%2C%20async,on%20a%20group%20of%20Promises%20.)

So, first: I would suggest you to fully undertand the different concepts above and ideas on how to handle them.

Then: decouple the different concepts you're talking about in your question. They mean different things and there is no standard way to use them: you have to decide on their usage based on what you need and on what you're doing with your code.

To summarize it:

- Promise

> an object representing the eventual completion or failure of an asynchronous operation

- Callback

> a function passed into another function in which the latter will call the former once a particular status is reached (return point; error occurring; decision made; etc.)

- async/await

> this concept makes the asynchronous code appear and behave like synchronous code; and it simplifies the behavior of using promises synchronously and to perform some behavior on a group of promises

- try...catch

> a method to handle exceptions (!!!) - not necessarily a method to handle errors (normally an error will throw an exception but you might want or need to use it for different purposes too)

As you can see all these paradigms have different meanings and you can see them being used in conjunction in particular ways. However you are not necessarily forced to use them in the ways you normally see them being used.

**On the code**

This is the easy part when you fully understand the concepts:

- #1: Using callback mechanism --> you'll be connected to a MongoDB database or, if an error occurs during the process of establishing the connection, you'll return an error (via the callback mechanism)
- #2: Using a mix of function call `mongoose.connect` and chaining --> you're not handling eventual errors when connecting (so this will eventually be a problem); then, IF CONNECTED, if an error occurs during the time the connection is open, you're writing a warning to console; when the connection is open (if previous statement `mongoose.connect(...)` was successful, you're stating the DB is connected
- #3: Using the chaining concept only --> you're trying to establish a connection; then, if successful, you're connected; then, if not successul, you catch the error

Hope this helps. ;)